# Starting up rdebug connects, but then what am I to do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, rdebug

I'm using POW and Rdebug, and I have it all seemingly working because when I type :

```
rdebug -c
```

It returns :

```
Connected.
```

But now what? I have debugger placed in a partial call. I can tell the application hits the breakpoint because it stalls on the AJAX call, but no debug console comes up.

What am I missing?

Comment: You are supposed to see the debug console on the terminal you typed "rdebug -c" in, when you hit the debugger. So you are not seeing that?

Comment: It just sayed I'm connected, but no terminal prompt comes up when it hits the breakpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting Ruby-Debug to work with POW requires some configuration.

See the following [post by Pratik Naik](http://m.onkey.org/using-ruby-debug-with-pow) for details.